# Why does my player glitch to the top of the platforms when scrolling?

Tags: python, scroll, pygame, collision

Take note that I'm new to pygame. I was wondering why my player glitches on top of my platforms when it collides with them while scrolling on the x axis. And it's only while scrolling, not when the camera is static. Also, the vertical collisions work perfectly fine: it's only when moving horizontally that the bug happens. I've tried to switch the order of the vertical and horizontal collisions, but then it just makes the vertical collisions bug. I've also tried to move the player a bit to the opposite direction when it collides with a wall, but the problem remained. I also tried to move the player back by the scroll x speed, but that also didn't work. I tried to put the horizontal collisions in the scroll x function too, but that also failed. Any advice please?

Here's the scroll x and y functions:

```
def scroll_x(self):
                            player = self.player.sprite
                            player_x = player.rect.centerx
                            direction_x = player.direction.x

                            if player_x < screen_width / 4 and direction_x < 0:
                                            self.world_shiftx = 8
                                            player.speed = 0
                            elif player_x > screen_width - (screen_width / 4) and direction_x > 0:
                                            self.world_shiftx = -8
                                            player.speed = 0
                            else:
                                            self.world_shiftx = 0
                                            player.speed = 8

            def scroll_y(self):
                            player = self.player.sprite
                            player_y = player.rect.y
                            direction_y = player.direction.y

                            if player_y < screen_height / 3 and direction_y < 0:
                                            self.world_shifty = player.direction.y * -1

                            elif player_y > screen_height - (screen_height / 3) and direction_y > 0:
                                            self.world_shifty = player.direction.y * -1
                                            self.vertical_movement_collision()
                            else:
                                            self.world_shifty = 0
```

The collision functions:

```
def horizontal_movement_collision(self):
                            player = self.player.sprite
                            player.rect.x += player.direction.x * player.speed

                            for sprite in self.tiles.sprites():
                                            if sprite.rect.colliderect(player.rect):
                                                            if player.direction.x < 0:
                                                                            player.rect.left = sprite.rect.right
                                                            elif player.direction.x > 0:
                                                                            player.rect.right = sprite.rect.left

            def vertical_movement_collision(self):
                            player = self.player.sprite
                            player.apply_gravity()

                            for sprite in self.tiles.sprites():
                                            if sprite.rect.colliderect(player.rect):
                                                            if player.direction.y > 0:
                                                                            player.rect.bottom = sprite.rect.top
                                                                            player.direction.y = 0
                                                            elif player.direction.y < 0:
                                                                            player.rect.top = sprite.rect.bottom
                                                                            player.direction.y = 0
```

And the order the functions are executed:

```
 def run(self):
                            player = self.player.sprite
                            self.tiles.update(self.world_shiftx, self.world_shifty)
                            self.tiles.draw(self.display_surface)
                            self.scroll_x()
                            self.scroll_y()

                            self.player.update()
                            player.rect.y += player.direction.y + self.world_shifty
                            self.vertical_movement_collision()
                            self.horizontal_movement_collision()
                            self.player.draw(self.display_surface)
```

And if you need it, here's the player gravity function:

```
def apply_gravity(self):
                            if not self.direction.y < -16:
                                            self.direction.y += self.gravity
                            elif self.direction.y < -16:
                                            self.direction.y = -16
```

As well as the player jump function:

```
def jump(self):
                            if self.jumping == "false":
                                            if self.direction.y == 0:
                                                            self.jumping = "true"
                                                            self.direction.y = self.jump_speed
                            else:
                                            self.jumping = "false"
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you include the `apply_gravity` function? The problem might be there as well.

Comment: Just did. I also added the jump function in case you needed it.

Answer (score 0):

The `scroll_y` function causes the `vertical_movement_collision` function to execute after the tiles' position is shifted according to scroll, but before the player's position is shifted. When scrolling downwards, this can cause the top of the player to be unintentionally inside of one of the platforms. As the player's y direction is also positive (because the player's fall requires scrolling), all conditions are met for the `vertical_movement_collision` function to place the player at the top of the platform.

This problem can be solved by not calling `vertical_movement_collision` before the player's position is shifted. This can be implemented by one of the following solutions:

1. Remove the `self.vertical_movement_collision()` line from the `scroll_y` function.
2. Place the `player.rect.y += player.direction.y + self.world_shifty` line before the `self.scroll_y` call.
3. Place the `self.tiles.update(self.world_shiftx, self.world_shifty)` and `self.tiles.draw(self.display_surface)` lines after the `self.scroll_y` call.

It is possible that any of the above functions causes an unexpected error anywhere else in the program. If so, try another solution.